# In my calculator project, how to do operations for more than just two numbers?

Tags: java

For the addition of more than two numbers in my calculator, I did this:

```
public static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static void add(){
        double result = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter how many numbers you wanna add: ");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter all the numbers you wanna add:");
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
            result = result + a[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Result: "+result);
    }
```

but what to do in other operations (subtraction, multiplications, division) for more than just two numbers.

For subtraction, I tried to store the first number separately to subtract other numbers in it but it didn't work (I think my logic is wrong). Is there any way to do it and can I improve this somehow? It will help me in learning.

Comment: For subtraction and multiplication should it work when it works for addition. For division be careful because you are using integers and if you type in zero it will throw and error because dividing with zero is not possible

Comment: Nope, I tried but not working. It will print result in negative because it doesn't have anything to subtract with (so it'll assume: 0 - other numbers). That's why I tried to store first number separately but it's still not working. With this logic, program is subtracting the second number with the first number, ignoring the other numbers, and printing the result. And yes I'll add try and catch in the division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my logic was correct but I wrote it wrong in my code. lol

```
static void sub(){
        double result = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter how many numbers you wanna subtract: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter all the numbers you wanna subtract");
        int f = sc.nextInt();
        result = f - a[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
            result = result - a[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Result: "+result);
    }
```

Comment: make sure to mark this answer as accepted (green tick mark) if you feel like this is the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah! But when I do that the pop-up message appears - "You can accept your own answer tomorrow". So, I'll do it tomorrow.